# why this const is not getting value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this issue, I need to pass array values what I got from async function to objects to  display it on a FlatList but I am not receiving any value on objects to put on data={objects} returns undefined. I tried to check if objects was getting any value, it only gets value if a put on data={loadData()} after 3 times loaded. Also this will call the function infinity times.  this is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text , TextInput, View, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import  Object  from './Object';


export default function Content () {
  const [objects, setObjects] = useState([]);
    const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  
  const loadData = async () => {
        const res = await fetch(
            "https://us.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/search/item?namespace=static-us&name.en_US=Thunderfury&orderby=id&_page=1&access_token=privateToken"
        );
        const data = await res.json();
    console.log('data: ', data);
        setObjects(data);
    console.log(objects);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        loadData();
    
    }, []);
 
  
  return (
      <View style={styles.content}>
      <View style={styles.section} >
        <Text style={styles.logo}>Input </Text>
        <TextInput
                    style={styles.searchInput}
                    placeholder="Search an item"
                    placeholderTextColor="#858585"
                    onChangeText={(text) => text && setSearch(text)}
                />
        </View>

        
         <FlatList 
                    data={objects}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                renderItem={({ item }) => <Object object={item} style={styles.item}/>}
                refreshing={refreshing}
                onRefresh={ async () => {
          setRefreshing(true);
                    await loadData();
                    setRefreshing(false); 
        }}
            />
       
      </View>
     
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    content: {
    borderColor: 'black',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    height: '85%',
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    padding: 40,
    gap: 30,
  },
    section: {
        shadowRadius: '6px',
        borderColor: '#af9c81',
        height:  100,
        gap : 20,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        width: '100%',
        borderRadius: '20px',
        shadowColor:'#af9c81',
        shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 5},
        padding: 20,
    },
    section2: {
        shadowRadius: '6px',
        borderColor: '#af9c81',
        height:  400,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        width: '100%',
        borderRadius: '20px',
        shadowColor:'#af9c81',
        shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 5},
        padding: 20,
    }, 
    searchInput : {
      padding: 3,
    },
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine. The reason why `console.log(objects)` returns undefined is because it is run immediately after `setObjects(data)`.

State updates in React are asynchronous, meaning that React does not wait for the state to be updated before executing the next line of code. In your case, the state update `setObjects(data)` is not finished before `console.log(objects)` is run, and therefore it returns `undefined`.

To print when `objects` is updated, you can use

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("objects", objects);
}, [objects]);
```

Are you sure that you actually are getting any data from the endpoint? I have tried implementing your code with the endpoint https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json, which seems to work.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Text, TextInput, View, StyleSheet, FlatList } from "react-native";

export default function TabOneScreen() {
  const [objects, setObjects] = useState([]);
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  const loadData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(
      "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json"
    );
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log("data: ", data);
    setObjects(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("objects", objects);
  }, [objects]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.content}>
      <View style={styles.section}>
        <Text style={styles.logo}>Input </Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.searchInput}
          placeholder="Search an item"
          placeholderTextColor="#858585"
          onChangeText={(text) => text && setSearch(text)}
        />
      </View>

      <FlatList
        data={objects}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Text> {item} </Text>}
        refreshing={refreshing}
        onRefresh={async () => {
          setRefreshing(true);
          await loadData();
          setRefreshing(false);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  logo: {
    width: "100%",
  },
  content: {
    borderColor: "black",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    height: "85%",
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    padding: 40,
  },
  section: {
    borderColor: "#af9c81",
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    width: "100%",
    shadowColor: "#af9c81",
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 5 },
    padding: 20,
  },
  section2: {
    borderColor: "#af9c81",
    height: 400,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    width: "100%",
    shadowColor: "#af9c81",
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 5 },
    padding: 20,
  },
  searchInput: {
    padding: 3,
  },
});
```

Comment: objects is empty at first attemp. then getting values after 1 autorefresh, is there any way to get this data or api call before app loads? Im trying to use a filter on <FlatList data={objects.filter(.....)} since objects is not declared at first or before this component is loaded , Console is prompting "objecst.filter" is not a function

Comment: My guess it complains, because the data from the endpoint is not an array, but an object which contains a nested array. E.g. the name of the array in the object could be results, and then you should write data={objects?.results.filter(.....)}. Remember  to redefine the object state as const [objects, setObjects] = useState(); (i.e. without the [] in its initializor).